# Recursion vs Common Table Expression - when to use CTE?

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Given the following table schema, I was asked how to find all subordinates of Annie.

```
-----------------------------
EmployeeId | Name | ManagerId
-----------------------------
1          | Annie| NULL
2          | Ben  | 1
3          | Carl | 2
4          | Den  | 1
....
```

Coming from ORM & server-side background, I'd write a recursive func to solve the problem. However, I was told there is a different way using CTE. Why and when we use CTE ? Why not recursion ? Is CTE faster than recursion ?

Anyway, here is my recursive implementation:

```
public class Employee{
    int employeeId;
    string name;
    public List<Employee> managers {get;set};
    public List<Employee> subordinates {get;set};
}

//find direct & non-direct reports
public List<Employee> getSubordinates(Employee emp) {
    List<Employee> reports = new List<Employee>();
    if (emp.subordinates == null || emp.subordinates.Count == 0) 
       return null;

    foreach(Employee e in emp.subordinates) {
       reports.AddRange(getSubordinates(e));
    }

    return reports.DistinctBy(x=>x.employeeId);
}
```

Comment: Using a `CTE` you can implement recursion on the server-side, and thus return the required result set with a single query. You can find plenty of examples of how to do this here is SO.

Answer (score 0):

Common Table Expressions (CTEs) would help you [accomplish recursion](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) from the database side, so really you would be accomplishing the same thing as your method with the key exception being that it is done with one query through SQL, e.g.:

```
WITH subordinates AS (
    SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.Name
    FROM dbo.Employee e
    WHERE e.ManagerId = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.Name
    FROM dbo.Employee e
        INNER JOIN subordinates s ON s.EmployeeId = e.ManagerId
)
SELECT s.EmployeeId, s.Name
FROM subordinates s;
```

The benefit is that it is potentially faster since it is being done in one query vs several queries generated from the recursive ORM method.

[T-SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/340e9/8)